# Update query not working - Webmatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I am doing a simple update query that just doesn't update the database. Can somebody please tell me whats wrong with the code?

```
        if(IsPost){
    JobID = Request.Form["JobID"];
    Status = Request.Form["Status"];

    var db = Database.Open("VouchFor");
    var updateCommand = "UPDATE Referral SET Status=@1 WHERE JobID=@0";
        db.Execute(updateCommand, JobID, Status);
        Response.Redirect("~/Account/Dashboard");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code looks correct.  I suspect the problem is in your HTML where you are defining the form.  Carefully review it and make sure there's like:

```
JobID = UrlData[0];
...
```

and then

```
<form method="post>
   ...

   <input type="text" name="Status" value=""/>
   ...
</form>
```

or maybe you are setting the JobID when you create the page?  Kindly post your whole cshtml.

Comment: <form method="post">

    <h3>Set availability for this referral</h3>
      
<div class="form-group">

     <select class="form-control" name="Status">
                <option value="Avaialable">I am open to this opportunity</option>
                <option value="Unavailable">I am currently unavailable</option>
     </select>

        </div> 
  
    <p><h2><input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Set  availability" /></h2></p>
                   


      </form>

Comment: I think the problem is the missing JobID - How does the page know which JobID you are on?   Perhaps it's in the URL?

Comment: Yes it is in the URL

Comment: Aha!  Change your line where you define JobID to get the ID from the URL.  It's not part of the form.  I changed my answer to show how to do this.